# Uncertainty Principle and Commutators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

In preparation for an exam I stumbled upon a quantum mechanics task I can´t really solve right know. So i hope someone can maybe give me a hint or two how to understand this. Here is the task:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two hermitian operators of a quantum mechanical system and $C = [A,B]$ is their commutator. What does the uncertainty principle give as the supremum for the product of the standard deviation of the measurables $A$ and $B$ (same prepared state every time)? Is this limit independent from the state the measurements were taken in?

I don´t really have a clue how to find an upper limit for the product. I thought of C being hermitian so that A and B commute but then the product of the standard deviation is just bigger then 0 and I dont have an upper limit. I´m kinda confused where this question is heading.

Comment: Maybe a typo?  “upper limit” doesn’t make obvious sense... *lower* limit would.

Comment: I think I meant supremum not upper limit. As this was a german task I didnt get the translation right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: For that you can actually use the Robertson-Schrodinger uncertainty relation, which you can find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations. However, I think you should be talking about the lower limit, as there's no upper limit regarding the uncertainty.

Comment: yeah, this quadratic formula came to mind when reading the OP.

Comment: That´s what I thought too and that´s why I´m kinda confused, but the task is stated like that. I think I will need to find out if that´s an error by the professor who wrote that task or if there is something I did miss out. Thanks for your help!